# Which parser combinator works on Data.Text and is included in vanilla GHC?

Tags: parsing, haskell, text

Is there a parser combinator available in GHC which satisfies the following two constraints:

- works with input of type `Data.Text`
- is included in the default GHC distribution

For example, `Text.ParserCombinators.ReadP` is included in GHC but does not work with `Data.Text`. Another example is `attoparsec` which works with `Data.Text` but is not included in GHC.

Solution: `parsec` sattisfies the two constraints but `attoparsec` does not

Comment: I don't think there is one, but given that `Data.Text` itself isn't in the GHC core libraries, why is it a big deal to use a second thing that isn't?

Comment: I'm not allowed to use `cabal`, `stack` or something similar and I'm using GHC from the Fedora modules repository which means that all the other Haskell libraries from the Fedora repository depend on the GHC version shipped in the regular Fedora repository. Thus everything which isn't shipped within GHC is problematic for me.

Comment: But `Data.Text` itself isn't shipped within GHC.

Comment: And if you want to use Parsec, Fedora has a `ghc-parsec` RPM in their repository.

Comment: In F32 `ghc-parsec` is build against GHC from the _release_ / _updates_ repository which is version 6.8. However, I'm using GHC from the _modules_ repository which is version 8.10 which is not compatible with `ghc-parsec` from the _release_ / _updates_ repository.

Comment: But again, that would mean that you can't use `Data.Text` at all anyway.

Comment: `Data.Text` is shipped with GHC, see https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/packages/text/-/blob/master/Data/Text.hs

Comment: Not everything on GHC GitLab ships with GHC. And even if it did, then there wouldn't be a question there, since Parsec is there too: https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/packages/parsec/-/blob/master/src/Text/Parsec.hs

Comment: My bad, in my initial question I spoke about `parsec` but actually ment `attoparsec`. According to your link `parsec` is included in GHC which I can confirm at least on F32. I updated the question in order to reflect this. Thx!

Comment: you can post an answer to your own question. Now that you have your answer you should do that.

Comment: Its not terribly difficult to role your own (basic) parser combinator once you define the monad instance for `Text -> Maybe (a, Text)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One parser which satisfies the constraints is `parsec`.